# ¿Cómo copiar un archivo de recurso que utiliza mi proyecto al directorio de compilación y que este lo reconozca automáticamente en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows, windows10

espero estén bien, el motivo de la presente es para hacer una consulta.

Tengo un Proyecto que al hacer clic sobre el botón de ayuda me abra un MSGBOX con el contenido de un archivo de texto, mi código es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub BotónAyuda_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotónAyuda.Click
    Dim filereader As String 'Variable Filereader
    filereader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\produ\Documents\GeckLab\Resources\Ayuda.txt") 'Directorio del Archivo de Texto
    MsgBox(filereader)
End Sub
```

Lo que pasa es que al ejecutarlo en otra pc me sale una excepción en el Net.Framework ya que no encuentra el archivo.

Mi duda en cuestón es que ¿Cómo lo puedo copiar al directorio de compilación y que lo reconozca automáticamente sin dar excepciones.

Gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que el archivo se copia a la carpeta de instalación de la aplicación:

- Selecciona el archivo
- Pulsa F4 para editar sus propiedades
- Establece el valor de la propiedad "Copiar en el directorio de salida" a "Copiar siempre"

Para leer el archivo deberías utilizar una ruta relativa a la carpeta de instalación de la aplicación:

```
Private Sub BotónAyuda_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BotónAyuda.Click
    Dim filereader As String 'Variable Filereader
    Dim exeFile As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    Dim exeDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile)
    filereader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(exeDir, "Resources\Ayuda.txt"))
    MsgBox(filereader)
End Sub
```

Comment: Pues es una salida... pero, ¿no sería más simple poner en la línea filereader "My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("Resources\Ayuda.txt")?, digo como en HTML, que en él no importa en qué máquina esté, sólo los busca en su carpeta origen y sus subcarpetas.